# Limit on number of items in lookup column dropdown list when attaching content types to document libraries

Tags: sharepoint

I've got a content type attached to a document library that includes a lookup column that references a list of active projects. The idea is that anyone creating a new document in the library needs to specify the project # of the project the document pertains to.

It appears that the dropdown list that appears at the top of the Word document only displays the first 100 items from the active projects list however. Does anyone know if this is a known issue with SharePoint 2007? I am not seeing this problem when using the same lookup column in lists as opposed to content types.

Regards.